# PyInstaller-2.1 Gives out error sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite, ubuntu-11.04

I used PyInstaller-2.1 to compile a script to executable on Ubuntu 11.04. On Windows, the output works fine with the SQLite database but on Ubuntu it gives me the error: **error sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked**.

Can anyone please explain to me what may be the cause of it? Thanks.